# LINQ Group by with where condition in Data table using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatable, webforms

I am very new in LINQ and trying group by with where condition.

Below is my code working fine without where condition.

```
 List<DataTable> result = dt.AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id")) 
      .Select(grp => grp.CopyToDataTable())
      .ToList();
```

In my datatable dt getting this data.

```
 row_id         name
  0              Mazhar
  0              Raj
  1              Khan
  1              Ravi
```

I need to separate row_id=0 and row_id=1 data.

Comment: it would be better if you could describe what you are trying to do (rather than what the code should look like)

Comment: in my dt I am getting data with row_id=0 and row_id=1. So I am trying to separate row_id=0 and row_id=1 data and row_id are fixed in dt.@M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: I updated my question please check above. @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: Why do you need the `where` condition? `GroupBy` does what you explained.

Comment: List<DataTable> result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id") == 0)
             .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id"))
             .Select(grp => grp.CopyToDataTable())
             .ToList();  i got my answer from my self.@L_J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Where clause below would filter results where rowId = 0.

```
List<DataTable> result = dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(w => w.Field<int>("row_Id") == 0)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id")) 
  .Select(grp => grp.CopyToDataTable())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: After the `Where` the `GroupBy` does nothing.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like after filtering by one of the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>( )
                            .Select( x => new { ID = x.ItemArray[0], ROW = x } )
                            .GroupBy( x => (string)x.ID )
                            .ToList( );
```

This LINQ separates row_id = 0 to row_id = 1.
If you need a `iEnumerable` of `DataRow`:

```
        var result0 = result.Where( x => (string)x.Key == "0" ).FirstOrDefault( ).Select( x => x.ROW ).ToList( );
        var result1 = result.Where( x => (string)x.Key == "1" ).FirstOrDefault( ).Select( x => x.ROW ).ToList( );
```